# How to use Rsync in terminal?

Tags: linux

I use windows 10 and install mvware to run centOS 6.5.

I try with rsync in terminal.

```
         rsync -avz + source + dest

        ===>>>>  rsync -avz /John/ServerA/* /John/ServerB/
```

the file and directory are transfered, but when I edit config.txt file in ServerA (source) the serverB (Dest) not change. means it not synchronized.

please, give me expert.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for periodic syncing or are you running the rsync command each time you edit?

Comment: running rsync each tme I edit.

Comment: I have a few theories but before I jump to answer, try running your rsync command with an additional option `--log-file=myrsynclog.txt`. Then you could check the contents to see what is going on with each rsync run.

Comment: I never use this option. It gives me an action date while transfering.

Comment: Does it say if the rsync was successful or not? What does the output of the command itself say?

Comment: But I need all of you to know that in my case. I test it in centOS 6.5 in terminal not use the real server.

Comment: No, fiist say building file list and then received xx byte  like that.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities.. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.